# Getting nil values when request ride details Uber

Tags: swift, uber-api

I'm trying to fetch details of rides that didn't originate in my app but keep getting nil values.

I first login using the Uber iOS SDK and request history / all-trip scopes. I then fetch the ride history. Using request-ids from ride history, I fetch ride details.

In every ride object returned, all values except status, requestID and ProductID are always nil.

I'm aware this is a privileged scope, and haven't requested full access yet. My user should work as it's on the dev dashboard though.

Any idea? Thanks!

```
let ridesClient = RidesClient()

    //Fetch history of most recent rides
    ridesClient.fetchTripHistory(offset: 0, limit: 20) { (history, response) in
        if (response.error == nil){ //Success
            if let history = history {

                //Loop into trips
                for trip in history.history {
                    //Fetch trip details
                    ridesClient.fetchRideDetails(requestID: trip.requestID, completion: { (ride, response) in
                        //Ride object is valid but everything in it is nil
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        else { //Error
            print(response.error?.description as Any)
        }
    }
```

[Screenshot to trip object](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjha2jux64ua2t4/Screenshot%202017-10-15%2018.31.18.png?dl=0)

Comment: Please clarify your question by posting your code

Comment: Added code and a screenshot to the trip object. I'm reading many objects, they all come back the same way

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a valid response back from the `/v1.2/requests/51c4db1d-2f3d-4c8a-8577-e02490c30e22` endpoint call. This trip is completed - so you will be able to get only trip status. If you are getting "null" values when you call this endpoint - there are no any issues with the call and response you are getting back - it is intentionally made to be "null".

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sasa. Just to be sure, this means there is no way for me to get details of a trip after it has been completed? Or would there be another call / another scope that could give me that data?

Comment: And if not, I assume the only way for us to get that data would be through a webhook while the ride is active?

Comment: Webhook option and getting the trip details on status change is better option to get more details about the trip.

Comment: Also, you may consider using history endpoint: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/history-get

Comment: Perfect thanks. And yes, I'm already using the history call, although I need more information on the pickup / dropoff location which I originally hope to get from details call. Will look into the webhook then. Thanks for your help